# How to validate input text for integers and decimals only?

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-validation

I cannot find the right answer for my case, so I posted my question here.

I'm validating the form in ASP.NET MVC and looking for the way to validate a text field to allow only numeric and decimal numbers like

1 or 1.5 or 1.65

If I have 1,65 I do not want this to be validated.

I have put a metadata on my Model's field like this: `[RegularExpression(@"^(((\d{1})*))$")]`

And have

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ResolvedAmount, "", new { @class = "error" })
```

to validate the field.

Also, in my function I have the following to check the validation:

```
var validator = $("#main").kendoValidator().data('kendoValidator'); 

if(validator.validate()){some logic}
```

I validate for the required field, but cannot get my int/decimal validation working.

What do I need to have in order to validate it?

Comment: `cannot get my int/decimal validation working`: What works, what does not work? E. g. if you enter "1", does the validation work? I. e. is this a question about the regular expression or one about the validation framework?

Comment: any numbers works except of something like that 1,65 or 5,89.  1.65 works for example. I also can have 1234567.99 but cannot have 1234567,99

Comment: Try `@"^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$"`

Comment: @gene By `works`, do you mean "this part of the code does not cause problems in the application" - which is what I was asking? From your answer, I would assume you mean "the application should allow", i. e. you were clarifying the requirements. But my first comment wanted to have a clarification of which parts of your code had the desired result, and where you were struggling. You just put there some code without telling and asked what you need to change. It would help readers to know what already works, so that they can concentrate on the parts that need to be changed.